# Flutter, better performance with Future.delay or Timer?

Tags: performance, flutter, timer, cross-platform, delay

in flutter, if i need to execute a refresh every 60 seconds or do some code... in performance..
is better to use

```
Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: (seconds * 1000)), () {

// Here you can write your code
       
});
```

or it's better

```
Timer  _timer = new Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: (seconds * 1000)), () {
     // Here you can write your code
});
```

or (suggested by Omer Gamliel )

```
   Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 60), (timer) {
       // Here you can write your code
   });
```

what do you think?

Comment: you can also use Timer.periodic

Comment: they both are the same, visit https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future/Future.delayed.html and check `Implementation` on the bottom

Comment: @pskink ok, do you intend in performance? cpu etc...?

Comment: @pskink now i see! so, help me to understand, future delayed is a timer masked by the function future delayed?

Comment: yes, it uses `Timer` internally

Answer (score 3):

According to the comment of pskink

[Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future/Future.delayed.html)

Flutter documentation show that Future.delayed is a Timer masked for convenience by the function Future.delayed to execute only once.

So, they are equal.

Answer (score 1):

A delayed runs only once so I think Timer is the better one

Comment: thank you! but i can write another delayed inside and repeat

Comment: It's all about convenience. Timer provides you with the convenience of cancelling it from within or anywhere within the scope of the Timer instance